# Moving C# SQLite Program to new Machine

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I have a SQLite Database already filled with tables and data, my program reads and writes from this table already.

However I need to deploy this Program on other machines and when I do I get the error

> "SQL Logic Error or missing database no such table: Customer"

The SQLite database is saved in the root of the C Drive, and it is there on the machines I have tested on.

This is my Connection String

```
 Data Source= "C:\EpasSqLite.db"; Version = 3;
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does it work if you run your program as administrator?

Comment: Is this not a permissions error?

Comment: I will try now running as admin

Comment: You need administrator privileges to write to the root directory for the same security reasons that you can't write to the Program Files directory. Either put your data in the [Application Data directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) or create a new folder where the user won't need to use administrator permissions.

Comment: Yes! Changed the folder to C/Test/ and run as administrator and it works! So thank you everyone

Comment: @sgmoore consider providing this as an answer as it solves the issue...